# Laptop Power Management - Inspiron 5555

Tags: power-management

My Dell Inspiron 5555 has an AMD A10 CPU/GPU:

```
 processor  : 3
   vendor_id    : AuthenticAMD
   cpu family   : 21
   model        : 96
   model name   : AMD A10-8700P Radeon R6, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G
```

Ubuntu is up to date 16.04.1 LTS.  The amdgpu driver is installed.

1. I have the laptop plugged in to a KillAWatt power meter.  If I allow the power manager to manage the display, when the display is blanked on idle, the power consumption jumps from 20 watts to 30 watts.  This makes the fans come on pretty loud. I would not expect that blanking the display would have that effect.
2. If I disable power management for the display altogether, the laptop still draws just under 20 watts.  The CPU frequencies seem to be 1300, 1600 and 1800 MHz.  Can I get the CPU to drop to a lower frequency when idle? Or turn off cores?